# Sum Accumulated Power BI DAX

Tags: powerbi, sum, dax, accumulate

I have two columns, a measure and a date that when I put in my visual table I use the hierarchy and see only the month, I want to obtain the accumulated sum of "sum" by month and year,
I attach an image of my data, the yellow column is what I should obtain and the green column is the result I have.

[image]

I already used the formula

```
TOTALYTD( REBATES_COM[net month], REBATES_COM[Posting Date])
```

and it doesn't give me the accumulated amount if I don't keep getting the green column.

Any idea what I can do?

Comment: Is `net month` a measure or column? If measure, what is its expression? Also see this other closely related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77908395/get-previous-month-value-power-bi-dax Is this homework?

Comment: Hello @Sam Nseir, yes it is a measurement, the result of the subtraction of two other measurements